# Улучшение кода PHP

Tags: php

Имеется код для отображения таблицы:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'vladiksan1998', 'JszwM4xj24Q')
    or die('Не удалось соединиться: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('vladiksan1998') or die('Не удалось выбрать базу данных');

$query = 'SELECT * FROM records';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Запрос не удался: ' . mysql_error());

echo "<table>\n";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($line as $col_value) {
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Необходимо отобразить таблицу в js, для этого используется ajax:

```
var tutajax = $.ajax( "otobr.php" ) 
            .done(function(data) { 
            console.log(data); 
            }) 
        .fail(function() { 
            console.log("error"); 
            });
```

Но при передаче таблицы она передаётся в формате:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Иван</td>
        <td>Иванов</td>
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Анатолий</td>
        <td>Анатольевич</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Анатолий</td>
        <td>Толя</td>
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Анатолий</td>
        <td>Толя</td>
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Анатолий</td>
        <td>Толя</td>
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

как можно изменить php код, что бы "таблица" выводилась в формате:

Иван Иванов 15

Анатолий Анатольевич 3